# Netplan: accept terms and conditions

Tags: networking, network-manager, netplan

I have an ubuntu-server installed on a raspberry pi 4.
The ubuntu server is using netplan for network configuration.

I wan to connect to an open wifi network called "WiFi4EU".
But when I want to connect, I have to accept the terms and conditions off this network.
If I use a windows pc to connect to this network, I need to use the browser to go to a login page where I need to accept the terms and conditions of this network.

Can I use netplan to configure this network? Or are there other ways to configure this?

If I use this configuration in */etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml* will I then be able to connect?

```
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
    wifis:
        wlan0:
            access-points:
                WiFi4EU: {}
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netplan does not handle captive portals on Wifi.  You will still need to open a browser to connect.

Comment: So I have to install ubuntu desktop instead of ubuntu server, and then I can use any browser to connect?

Comment: Yes, the easiest way to get a browser here is to install the Ubuntu desktop image

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) to open Firefox, accept the European Union Free WiFi license agreement and then close Firefox.

Being in Canada I can NOT write and test this as it needs to be done in an EU municipality. You will need to use Python, Java or C to get the job done.

Comment: Can I also open Firefox manualy, so I don't need Selenium? If I install ubuntu desktop in stead of ubuntu server that I currently use?

Comment: @Jarne Yes of course. I assumed you wanted the server to automatically open WiFi when it booted up. That would call for an automated process. Naturally manual process works too!